# Laravel routes and correct workflow

Tags: php, laravel, coding-style, standards

I have just recently got into MVC and Laravel and have a question about what the correct way of handling things is.

Let's say I am building a website with it's CMS or something similar.

I have a landing page www.website.com, with the CMS at www.website.com/cms/

The CMS has a navigation menu, whose each item represents a table in the DB.

Let's say - Accounts | Articles | Menu - Clicking on each item should bring the list of the records in each of the tables.

To do this do I :

a) Have a route

```
Route::get('cms/{requestedtable}', 'PagesController@CmsCreate');
```

And in this route I would

```
switch($requestedtable)
   case 'accounts';
      $data = Account::all();
   case 'menu'
      $data = Menu::all();
```

b) Have a route for each item

```
Route::get('cms/accounts/', 'AccountController@index');

public function index() {

   Account::all()
```

Same for inserting, updating and deleting. Would it be more correct to create a route for each of the events

```
Route::get('cms/accounts/', 'AccountController@index');
Route::get('cms/accounts/create', 'AccountController@create');
Route::get('cms/accounts/update', 'AccountController@update');
```

Or just one route but using a different function

```
Route::get('cms/{{requestedtable))/update', 'PageController@CmsUpdate');
```

What I am afraid of with the dynamic option, is that I am gonna have a 30 deep switch if I have 30 tables. But then again I am also gonna have 30 controllers if I have 30 tables. I always want to keep my code as standarized (is that even a word) as possible, even if I am the only one working on it. I like to do things the correct way.

Thanks for any input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's no right or wrong and both ways are valid, although I prefer to have a lot of routes than having one route with an wildcard and adding extra logic. It just seems wrong and I assure you that in the future you will regret it.

Also I noticed that you interested in doing the typical CRUD operations, using a [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) is a good way to keep your `routes.php` clean. Notice that although Resource Controllers are commonly used in REST APIs you can use them in any web application.

This is how your routes.php would be:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cms'], function()
{
  Route::resource('Accounts','AccountsController');
  Route::resource('Articles','ArticlesController');
  Route::resource('Menu','MenuController');
});
```

And this will be the routes available:
[image: php artisan route:list]

Notice that you can also use wildcards on resource controllers as stated [here](http://laravel.io/forum/08-04-2014-wildcard-in-resource-controller):

```
Route::resource('{resource}', 'PagesController');
```

Comment: Literally 2 mins after creating this article I moved to the next episode of Laracasts and it was about Routes and Resources. This is an elegant solution which I will go with! Thanks.